# Column is not showing up in datagridview even after adding columns in microsoft sql studio

Tags: c#, sql

My data grid view is not working. I added two new columns called Lockup no  and Status in Microsoft sql server studio and saved it. When connecting to the DGV in visual studio, it is not showing those two newly added columns? I have already tried by creating third new dataset but still those two new columns are not appearing. 
I am using visual studio 2017.

```
private void GetPrisonersRecord()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Prisoner_Record",con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       con.Open();
       SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(sdr);
        con.Close();
        PrisonerRecordDATAGRIDVIEW.DataSource = dt;

    }
```

This Code is what I am using to get all the records in the dataGridView
[Look here. The columns appearing in sql server management studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoyID.png)

but not appearing in [Visual studio DATAGRIDVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X3cE.png)

Comment: Are your newly added columns appearing in ur datatable?

Comment: They are appearing in sql server management studio but they are not appearing in visual studio data grid view

Comment: Have you debug your code? What's there in your datatable?

Comment: I have tried debugging. It doesn't work. It shows previous column but not the newly added ones. I added new ones manually in sql server studio(SSMS).

Comment: I have edited the post and added two pics. First image is showing new columns called Status and Lockup no. Second Image is showing they are not appearing in DGV in visual studio

Comment: Your database table has only 4 columns and there are more columns in your datagridview. I think the column mapping is done manually in the design mode.

Comment: Actually I didnt upload full picture of those columns. When I first created this data table it included (Id,name,crime,punishment,from,to ) columns only. Then later I added two more(Lockup no and Status) columns which are not appearing.

Comment: Sometimes deleting DGV an adding again help.  Properties in DGV get set wrong and easiest way of solving is to delete and add again.

Comment: Thankyou @jdweng Your advice worked.